# wp_mail function returns false in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sending email from `wp_mail` function in WordPress but it is not working it is returning false. I have tried with different things but it is not working. This is my code:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: xxx@gmail.com' . "\r\n";
$mailResult = false;
$to = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
$subject = "xxxxxx";
$message = "Testing Mailgun at: ";
$mailResult = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers);
$myarr= array('error' => true, 'mail' => $mailResult);
echo json_encode($myarr);
```

I have also tried without `$headers` variable but it is still not working:

```
$mailResult = wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message);
```

[image]

Comment: Is there anything written to any error log?

Comment: @NicoHaase I have attached Image

Comment: That is not the error log. Have a look at your server's error log, or provide other information about that problem. Currently, there is not enough information to help

Comment: there is no error log of today..